# Translate proposition into formal language

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Knowing that predicate $P(x)$ means '$x$ is a prime number' and $a/b$ denotes '$a$ is a divisor of $b$' express the following using logical operators, quantifiers, etc: 'number $z$ is a divisor of the sum of two prime numbers'.

How would I go about doing that?
So far I came up with '$z/(P(x) + P(x))$' but honestly that seems too simple to be correct and I'm not sure if I can write the sum of two prime numbers like that.

Comment: Hint: Note that your formula has a variable x, but the expression you want to translate does not. Also you only speak about a single variable x, but we could have the sum of two different primes. Thirdly, P(x) is a predicate and hence you can not put it among terms i.e. P(x)+P(x) is not a well formed forula. P which say x is a prime will output true or false, but not x.

Answer (score 3):

"The number z is a divisor of the sum of two prime numbers", means: $$\text{There exists two numbers, which are both prime and z is a divisor of their sum.}$$

Is it easier to translate this statement into symbols?

**Hint:** You were asked to use "*logical operators, quantifiers, etc.*"   So can you now see where to do so?